# Unexpected behavior in the following Prolog program

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand how recursion works in Prolog. Consider the following program.

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(a,d).
edge(c,e).
path(d).
path(Vertex) :-  edge(Vertex, Next), write(Next), path(Next).
```

Run path(a).

output:

```
?- path(a).
bcd
true ;
ed
true;
false
```

What I don't quiet understand is the loop part of this program. So we start at a and then we go to b,c and d. Once we see d we stop. I can't understand the output 'ed' in the forth line. Why is it going to e,d and then returning true.  I also don't understand how the operator ';' works when querying another result. Does it mean get next possible result?

Another example: The following program writes all possible paths from one node to another node. I don't understand how loops work in this program to display different lists of paths.

```
 link( a, b ).
    link( a, d ).
    link( b, c ).
    link( d, e ).
    link( e, c ).
    link( e, f ).
    link( f, a ).
    link( f, g ).
    link( f, j ).
    link( g, h ).
    link( h, i ).
    link( i, j ).


not( X ) :- X, !, fail.
not( _ ).

writeallpaths( Node, Node ) :-
   write( Node ), write( ' is ' ), write( Node ), nl.
writeallpaths( Node, Next ) :-
   listpath( Node, Next, [Node], List ),
   write( Node ), write( ' to ' ), write( Next ), write( ' is ' ),
   writepath( List ),
   fail.

writepath( [] ) :-
   nl.
writepath( [Head|Tail] ) :-
   write( ' ' ), write( Head ), writepath( Tail ).

listpath( Node, End, Outlist ) :-
   listpath( Node, End, [Node], Outlist ).

listpath( Node, Node, _, [Node] ).
listpath( Node, End, Tried, [Node|List] ) :-
   link( Node, Next ),
   not( member( Next, Tried )),
   listpath( Next, End, [Next|Tried], List ).
```

Comment: You should get a basic textbook. Art of Prolog is good. Maybe there are better ones now.

Comment: The backtracking doesn't stop when `path(d)` is achieved as a goal. It continues and finds the `ce` path. It fails because it doesn't terminate in `d`, but because the predicate uses `write`, the path is written to the output before ultimate success or failure is determined. As @TomasBy suggests, if you are aren't sure what `;` does, you need to get a text book or do more reading of online Prolog documentation.

Comment: @TomasBy I am taking this example from a basic textbook.

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't understand how the operator ';' works when querying another result. Does it mean get next possible result?

Yes. What happens is that when you enter ; after finding the solution "bcd", Prolog tries to find alternative solution. In your case, it "goes back" (backtracks) to "c" because it has alternative path to "e" and continues search from there, until it reaches "d". Obviously, it doesn't print you the entire solution "bced", because Prolog does not go back to the very beginning, but rather only to "c", so only nodes after "c" are printed.

Also, you can always use trace/0 predicate which allows you to see in detail how Prolog executes your code.

Comment: what's weird is the output. I used write to print the next node. I don't understand why it prints ed true;